# is it possible to generate a jpg with javascript using text and other images

Tags: javascript, canvas, jpeg

I want to create jpg files with exercises that contain images and text. 
I want to use javascript.
I know it is possible with PHP but I cannot use that, it has to be Flash-less client-side.
maybe with the `<canvas>` element? But this will only work in HTML5

Pleh?

Comment: You can do this with easily a `<canvas>` -- simply draw the images and text onto the canvas and then get the canvas state as a `data:` URI using [`.toDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement).

Comment: Out of curiousity, why isnt php an option?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create it using canvas. But again, It will be only for html5 supported browsers and you can not achieve this using javascript in the browsers which dont support HTML5.